# Is there something better than VLOOKUP?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I'm wondering if there is something like a `VLOOKUP` for multiple matches in one column.

So, for example, if I have the following:

```
Alfred      red
Jone        orange
Christina   blue
Danielle    blue
Alfred      green
Jone        grey
```

If I do a vlookup for Alfred and Jone in some lookup reference cells returning the second column from table array above, it will only only return the first matches (red and orange), even if I have Alfred and Jone listed twice in my lookup cells.

Is there a way to do a vlookup so that subsequent listings will return what hasn't already been matched?

Comment: There isn't one function that will do this.  People have posted solutions before but non of them are very elegant.  Google vlookup second instance and you will find multiple discussions on this, sorry don't have links right now.

Comment: If you don't mind returning the values in more than a single cell, you might try autofilter or advanced filter to return all adjacent content

Comment: The search functions in Excel always return just one value. A workaround is to use filters on your data, as said by @datatoo.

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

*Only by changing output format, meaningful results can be achieved.*

[image]

- An array (CSE) formula in cell D103 & fill right:

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$104:$A$109,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$103:C103,$A$104:$A$109),0)),"")}`
- Next insert this array (CSE) formula in cell D104, fill across:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$104:$B$109,SMALL(IF($A$104:$A$109=D$103,ROW($B$104:$B$109)-MIN(ROW($B$104:$B$109))+1),ROWS($D$104:D104))),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

*Finish both array (CSE) formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*